# Stop asking authentication in case of wrong credentials provided in svn export command

Tags: bash, shell, svn

This is my SVN URL to export a file:

```
svn export --username user --password pass "https://SVN_URL/PATH/file.java"
```

Here the username and password comes from parameter in a script, If user provides a wrong password, console allow us to re enter the credentials. This is perfectly OK, but I am using an App where no console will be visible to user. Here app stuck. No error/exception/message is thrown.

I was wondering is there any way where I got an error showing Invalid password/credentials.

thanks in advance.

Comment: has you checked for invalid certificate?

Answer (score 1):

Use `--non-interactive` option in scripts and [read the documentation](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.html#svn.ref.svn.sw.non_interactive).